# Installing Realm via CocoaPods in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoapods, realm

I keep getting return code 56 from cURL, which is caused by SSLRead returning errors -36 or -9806 in terminal "pod install":

Example 1:

```
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
sh build.sh cocoapods-setup

core is not a symlink. Deleting...
Downloading dependency: core 0.97.0
Downloading core failed:
curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -36
```

Example 2:

```
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
sh build.sh cocoapods-setup

core is not a symlink. Deleting...
Downloading dependency: core 0.97.0
Downloading core failed:
curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806
```

Has anyone faced this problem installing Realm?

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1022

Comment: Could you possibly be in China or going through a Chinese network? See https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2713

Comment: I'm currently not in china and I don't working through the chinese network.

Answer (score 0):

Check which version of xcode-select (Xcode command line tools) you are using. I have to switch between an older version and a newer version for building AOSP from source.

Check using:

```
gcc --version
```

The latest is `Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)`.

You can also check in Xcode by navigating to Xcode > Preferences, selecting the Locations tab and make sure Command Line Tools matches the version of Xcode you are using (mine says `Xcode 7.3.1`).

Answer (score 0):

You should download core via url first:

```
curl https://static.realm.io/downloads/core/realm-core-1.3.1.tar.bz2 -O
mkdir $TMPDIR/core_bin
mv realm-core-1.3.1.tar.bz2 $TMPDIR/core_bin
```

more detail in [github](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3183):

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you can access https://static.realm.io/downloads/core/realm-core-0.97.0.tar.bz2 by browser. If not, then it is the problem of your network.

Someone asks for solutions. So following is how I solved this.

download https://static.realm.io/downloads/core/realm-core-0.97.0.tar.bz2 using browser(as for me, I am using shadowsocks, so I can download it).

```
mkdir $TMPDIR/core_bin
mv realm-core-0.97.0.tar.bz2 core-0.97.0.tar.bz2 
mv realm-core-0.97.0.tar.bz2 $TMPDIR/core_bin
```

the third renaming operation depends on the real needed name used by realm. You should check out $TMPDIR/core_bin when realm starts to download.

Comment: This is not a solution to the question, is more a comment.

Comment: I cannot comment on other answers because of my low reputation.